# Is it possible to composite functions but keeps currying?

Tags: f#

For example, I can do this:

```
let mutable divide = fun (a,b) -> a / b
let checkZero (a,b) = if b = 0 then failwith "wrong" else (a,b)
divide <- checkZero >> divide

divide (5,3)
```

But what if I want to form a currying function:

```
let mutable divide = fun a b -> a / b
let checkZero a b = if b = 0 then failwith "wrong" else ... // How return
                                                     // the two argument
divide <- checkZero >> divide

divide 5 3
```

Can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The type of `>>` is:

```
> (>>);;
val it : (('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c) = <fun:it@3-1>
```

So `checkZero` and `divide` should obey type: `'a -> 'b`.

Comment: can `'a` be type `('e -> 'f)`

Comment: if `'a` can be `'e->'f`, then how can you resolve `'a->'b`, should it be `'a->'b`, or `('e->'f)->'b`, or `'a->('e->'f)`?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but doing something like this:

```
let curry f a b = f (a,b)
let uncurry f (a,b) = f a b

let mutable divide = fun a b -> a / b
let checkZero a b = if b = 0 then failwith "wrong" else (a,b)

divide <- let f = (uncurry checkZero) >> (uncurry divide) in curry f
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have two predicates, `checkZero` and `divide`, and you'd like to apply the same argument (a tuple) to both of these predicates.

Just like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109624/built-in-f-operator-to-compose-functions-with-the-same-input-but-different-outp): wrap `checkZero` into a combinator that would ignore the return value and return an original argument instead. Note that exception will be thrown when needed. Such combinator is defined in WebSharper:

```
let ( |>! ) x f = f x; x
// Usage:
let checkZero a b = if b = 0 then failwith "wrong" else ()
let ret = (5,3) |>! checkZero |> divide
```

This would work only if `checkZero` returns `unit`. If it is supposed to return something else (and the return value is supposed to be forcedly ignored), this definition will do the trick:

```
let ( |>!! ) x f = ignore(f x); x
// Usage:
let checkZero a b = if b = 0 then failwith "wrong" else "42"
let ret = (5,3) |>!! checkZero |> divide
```

The solution above seems to be the cleanest since it does not require modifying your predicates. The combinator will be reusable across the entire project.