# does a tee function exist somewhere in F# library?

Tags: f#

...or in FSharpx?

```
let tee sideEffect =
    fun x ->
        do sideEffect x
        x
```

The usage could be something like

```
f >> tee (printfn "F returned: %A") >> g >> h
```

Or is there another simple way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109624/built-in-f-operator-to-compose-functions-with-the-same-input-but-different-outp) question. It is largely related to yours, except you need a function, not an operator. Personally, I would suggest using `|>!` operator for workflows similar to the example in the accepted answer there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ExtCore includes a function called [`tap`](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/2adff09ca1ed6a555a8e6564203ec8dbfeeb76c8/ExtCore/Pervasive.fs#L210) which does exactly what you want. I use it for primarily for inspecting intermediate values within an F# "pipeline" (hence the name).

For example:

```
[| 1;2;3 |]
|> Array.map (fun x -> x * 2)
|> tap (fun arr ->
    printfn "The mapped array values are: %A" arr)
|> doOtherStuffWithArray
```

Answer (score 9):

The closest I've seen is actually in [WebSharper](http://websharper.com/). The definition is:

```
let inline ( |>! ) x sideEffect =
    do sideEffect x
    x
```

Usage:

```
(x |>! printf "%A") |> nextFunc
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of operators. Also if |>! is defined then I would expect >>! to be defined too. And why not !<| and !<< ? So it starts to get messy. So I would rather have the named function. But thanks for the link!

Comment: Sure! It's use in WebSharper is to attach event handlers to the DOM DSL Elements. (Which get translated into JavaScript.)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, a function like this isn't defined anywhere in the F# core library - though the library is missing many standard functions that are quite easy to define yourself, so my recommendation would be just to add it somewhere in your project - your `tee` seems like the best way to go.

That said, I'd probably prefer using less declarative style if I need side-effects and write something like:

```
let fResult = f fInput
printfn "F returned: %A" fResult
fResult |> g |> h
```

This is just a matter of style, but I prefer declarative style for fully declarative code and imperative style when there are side-effects involved. As a bonus, using local variables makes debugging easier. But using a function like `tee` is an equally good alternative that many people in the F# community would prefer.

Comment: I agree with you that declarative and imperative should be separated. My usage is during debugging purposes when I need to easily peek the intermediate results in a composition chain.